# How to retrieve the values in asp.net form from SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want the user entered values to get displayed in the form again.. my values get entered into the SQL Server database, but I don't know how to retrieve the values again in the form.. my code is:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Si-6\\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=emp;Integrated Security=SSPI");

try
{
   conn.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand ("insert into timeday(project,iteration,activity,description,status,hour)values('"+this .name1 .SelectedValue +"','"+this .iteration .SelectedValue +"','"+this .activity .SelectedValue +"','"+this.name2.Text+"','"+this.status .SelectedValue +"','"+this .Text1 .Text +"')",conn );

   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
   }
}
finally
{
   if (rdr != null)
      rdr.Close();

   if (conn != null)
      conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- avoid SQL injection and don't just concatenate together your SQL statements! Use **parametrized queries** instead!
- put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects into using blocks
- when you want to call an `INSERT` statement, definitely do **not** call `.ExecuteReader()` on your `SqlCommand` - use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead...

Try something like this:

```
string connStr = "Data Source=Silverage-6\\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=emp;Integrated Security=SSPI";

string queryStmt = 
   "INSERT INTO dbo.timeday(project, iteration, activity, description, status, hour) " + 
   "VALUES(@Project, @Iteration, @Activity, @Description, @Status, @Hour)";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, conn))
{
   _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Project", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
   _cmd.Parameters["@Project"].Value = this.name1.SelectedValue.Trim();

   // add other parameters the same way....

   conn.Open();
   int result = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```

It would be even better if you:

- would retrieve the connection string from a config file once, centrally, and just pass it into this method
- would retrieve the values to set from your web UI in your UI code, and then call this business method on a business logic object and pass in the values you've determined

Right now, you're wildly mixing UI code (retrieving the values from the dropdowns and textboxes) with database/business logic code - this is not a very solid design.....

**Update:** if you want to retrieve values and display them, you can use something like this:

```
public DataTable GetDataForProject(string projectName)
{
   string connStr = "Data Source=Silverage-6\\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=emp;Integrated Security=SSPI";

   string queryStmt = 
      "SELECT project, iteration, activity, description, status, hour " + 
      "FROM dbo.timeday " + 
      "WHERE project = @project";

   DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();

   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
   using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, conn))
   {
      _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Project", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
      _cmd.Parameters["@Project"].Value = projectName;

      SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
      dap.Fill(resultTable);
   }

   return resultTable;
}
```

Of course:

- you might want to select based on other criteria (that would show up in your `WHERE` clause)
- maybe you want to use a `SqlDataReader` and read that data into domain objects (instead of a `DataTable`)

but the basic setup - have a specific method, pass in criteria, read the data with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in using blocks - will remain the same.

Once you have the `DataTable`, you can bind it to an ASP.NET gridview:

```
DataTable projectData = GetDataForProject("MyProject");

gridView1.DataSource = projectData;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You have given the right path..how the code will be if i want to display the values from the database

Comment: @jeni: updated my answer with code to retrieve data from the database

Comment: this helps me a lot..I was new to sql.How can i go well with these objects like sqlconnection,sqlcommand,sqldatareader,sqldataadapter..I also want to clarify one more que with you.how to access the html control (id)using c#..thanks beforehand..

Answer (score 0):

After inserting you need to write a query to retrieve records.
Write this

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Silverage-6\\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=emp;Integrated Security=SSPI");

try
{
   conn.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand ();
   cmd.CommandText="insert into timeday(project,iteration,activity,description,status,hour)values('"+this .name1 .SelectedValue +"','"+this .iteration .SelectedValue +"','"+this .activity .SelectedValue +"','"+this.name2.Text+"','"+this.status .SelectedValue +"','"+this .Text1 .Text +"')";
   cmd.Connection=conn;

   int i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(i>0)
   {
      cmd.CommandText="Select * from timeday";
      rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while (rdr.Read())
      {
         Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
      }
   }
}
finally
{
   if (rdr != null)
      rdr.Close();

   if (conn != null)
      conn.Close();
}
```